# notifyitemchanged(position) refreshes the item in the list the first time but no more after that

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, notifydatasetchanged

Something very unusual is happening in my app. When I click on this view, I set the previous position to the current position so that next time I press the view, the method notifyItemChanged(position) will refresh the previous position. The weird thing is that it works like a charm the first time, but when it comes to the second time or third time and so on, it doesn't refresh the item. In the logcat everything  seems normal, too. It goes through the code with no warnings or errors. Here's my code:

My variable previous_pos is initialized at the top of my Adapter class.

```
private int previous_pos = -1;
```

This is a snippet of my Adapter class

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TrackHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mInstrumentalName.setText(tracks.get(position).getInstrumentalName());
    holder.mProducer.setText(tracks.get(position).getProducer());


    Log.d("position", Integer.toString(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
    holder.mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (previous_pos != -1) {
                notifyItemChanged(previous_pos);
            }

            previous_pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            holder.mPlayButton.toggle();



            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tracks.get(position).getMusicLink());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } else {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tracks.get(position).getMusicLink());
                    previous_link = tracks.get(position).getMusicLink();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }


        }
    });

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
            Toast.makeText(context, Integer.toString(tracks.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

holder.mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (previous_pos != -1) {
                notifyItemChanged(previous_pos);
            }

            previous_pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            holder.mPlayButton.toggle();



            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tracks.get(position).getMusicLink());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } else {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tracks.get(position).getMusicLink());
                    previous_link = tracks.get(position).getMusicLink();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `setOnClickListener` from `onBindViewHolder` to `onCreateViewHolder`.